# how to check for a particular string in another source string

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Can anybody please let me know how to check for a particular string in antoher string using VC++ 2003?

For Eg:

Soruce string - "I say that the site referenced here is not in configuration database. need to check";
String to find - "the site referenced here is not in configuration database"

can anybody please help me with this? Let me know if anymore clarity required.

Answer (score 3):

`std::string::find` might meet what you want, see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

```
string s1 = "I say that the site referenced here is not in configuration database. need to check"; 
string s2 = "the site referenced here is not in configuration database";

if (s1.find(s2) != std::string::npos){
    std::cout << " found " << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

string sourceString = "I say that the site referenced here is not in configuration database. need to check";

string stringToFind = "the site referenced here is not in configuration database";

**sourceString.find(stringToFind);**
This method call will return you the postion of type **size_t**

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

For C/C++, you can use `strstr()`:

> const char * strstr ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
>
> Locate substring
>
> Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of str2 in
>   str1, or a null pointer if str2 is not part of str1.

If you insist on pure C++, use `std::string::find`:

> size_t find (const std::string& str, size_t pos);
>
> Find content in string
>
> Searches the string for the content specified
>   in either str, s or c, and returns the position of the first
>   occurrence in the string.

Comment: Insist on pure C++? It should be reworded as insist on C.

Comment: I said exactly what I meant. Some people insist on pure C++ way of using `std::cout` instead of using old plain `printf`, even if that is not particularly efficient. In this case, plain C `strstr()` may be more efficient

Comment: @mvp: `strstr` is less efficient than `find`, because it needs to check each character against `'\0'`. `std::string` doesn't because it knows the length of the string at all times.